# Elegant way to modify yaml file in python

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to substitute environment variables list of yaml object in python.
The format of yaml file being:

```
environment:
- blocHost=bloc:8000
- EXT_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=${EXT_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET}
- EXT_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${EXT_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
```

The env vars loaded by `yaml.load()` is a list of strings, which is inconvenient to manipulate.
Is there any solution to load this list as a dictionary?
Thanks!

Comment: The YAML should be written as a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: You need to split the strings at `=` obviously, not `: ` as in the linked question.

Comment: Yes I think I might need to do some text manipulation to work this around. Thanks a lot!